# Reading consecutive pages in Acrobat starting with an odd page

Tags: windows

If I pick up a book, I see only the right-facing page. When I open the book, I see two pages, essentially page 2 and page 3. How do I look at pages 2 and 3 at the same time in a PDF document?

Answer (score 1):

We can try to set pages display as below:

Check "**View->Page Display->Two-Up**"

[image]

For details we can refer the article:
[Make It Look Like a Book in the Acrobat PDF](https://indesignsecrets.com/make-it-look-like-a-book-in-the-acrobat-pdf.php)